# position of options in HTML select element

Tags: html, css

I have a  element that contains options. The element is 150px wide but some of the options are wider. So when rendering, the browser shows the overflow to the right. How can I make the options list overflow to the left? **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bG4Jw/1/)**
The select is inside a div, on the top right corner, and it overflows outside to the left.

Thanks.

```
<select id="MySelect">
      <option value="60" selected="selected"></option><option value="-60">(UTC-01:00) Azores</option>
      <option value="-60">(UTC-01:00) Cape Verde Is.</option><option value="0">(UTC) Casablanca</option>
      <option value="0">(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London</option><option value="0">(UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik</option>
      <option value="60">(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague</option>
      <option value="60">(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
      <option value="60">(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb</option>
      <option value="60">(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa</option>
      <option value="120">(UTC+01:00) Windhoek</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

​#MySelect{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:200px;
    width:150px;}​​​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
<select id="MySelect" dir="rtl">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#MySelect{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:300px;
    width:150px;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

This is a pretty hacky way to do it, but it works. I can't think of any other way.